# Using variable outside of PHP class, without referencing class first

Tags: php, class

Is it possible to have a PHP class and set up a variable inside of the class in such a way that it can be used without referring to the class first. In other words, can such a variable somehow be made a global? Or if not a global, what code could make a variable outside a class refer to the one inside the class.

Class Example:

```
class A {
    $my_var = '';
}
```

Code Example:

```
$new_a = new A();
$my_var = 'some string'; 
//This should change the variable inside the class, 
//without having to call $new_a->my_var = 'some string';
```

Is this in any way possible?

Thank you
Michael

Comment: How could php know you mean the variable inside the class?

Comment: Global state is very very very bad.  If you can do what you want in PHP then I really don't want to know how!

Comment: @damien-pirsy That is exactly what I want to know. What code would make php understand that i am referring to the variable inside the class.

Comment: @MichaelFrey that would be `$new_a -> my_var`

Comment: As with many questions here on SO, my question after reading this one is: **why on earth** would you want that. Please explain some of the context so people can help with your original problem, since this is a solution you came up with that causes more problems. Let us help solve the original problem, not this crazy one.

Comment: I'll add to some bad practices: add `$my_var =& $new_a->my_var;` right after setting `$new_a`

Answer (score 1):

No. 
If you do that, you will have a new variable called $my_var which has nothing to do with the field in your class.